# What could cause a layoutTemplate's helpers to be rerun?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm navigating between two routes that have the same `layoutTemplate`. By default, the layout helpers are not rerun:

http://meteorpad.com/pad/TP6QoWiryAde6du6u/Copy%20of%20IR

However, in my app, they are – even a one-line helper that just calls `console.log`. Note that:

- the layout's `onRendered` is not called again.
- it only happens going from and to a single route, but not the others

What are the reasons why this could happen?

Comment: well, if the helper uses any reactive data source and that data changes, then the helper will re-run. That's definitely thing that can cause it, but without seeing your code it's impossible to say whether that's the cause here.

Comment: A single helper that has a reactive data source would not make the other helpers (eg the one that just `console.log`s) run as well, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking this out of that single route fixed it!

```
data: ->
  code: @params.code
```

Replaced with `Router.current().data()?.code` in helpers & `onRendered`.